# genaction not found in diamondback

Tags: navigation, move-base, ros-diamondback, actionlib

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am transferring all my cturtle files to diamondback. While compiling actionlib for my move_base i get following error:

```
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> robot_move [ make ]                                                                                
[ rosmake ] All 14 linesskorta_move: 0.3 sec ]                                                       [ 1 Active 0/1 Complete ]
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  mkdir -p bin
  cd build && cmake -Wdev -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=`rospack find rosbuild`/rostoolchain.cmake  ..
  CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:13 (include):
    include could not find load file:
  
      /opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/common/actionlib/cmake/actionbuild.cmake
  
  
  CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:14 (genaction):
    **Unknown CMake command "genaction".**
  
  
  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
```

I did not find genaction.py file in the folder

Any help on this would be appreciated.
Prasad

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9380/genaction-not-found-in-diamondback/) by [Prasad](https://answers.ros.org/users/61/prasad/) on ROS Answers with karma: 79 on 2011-03-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to change actionlib to actionlib_msgs in the include line.  See the [actionlib wiki page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/actionlib)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-03-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2